Can We Assign Different Taxonomies values to Different Language Versions of a Product in Sitecore Content Hub PCM?
For example, I have Product-A, and this product has a relation with the taxonomy "Country" which has multiple values. I want the English version of Product-A to be tagged with the taxonomy value "USA" and the German version of the same product to be tagged with the taxonomy value "Germany." Is this possible in Sitecore Content Hub PCM? How can this be achieved?

In order to address this, you can create a separate entity(i.e. ProductTranslation) inside which you can create the fields you would like to translate for another country. Then create a relation between this entity and Product as one to many using Taxonomy Relation.
Once the relation is created, then inside the Product Detail page, you can attach a Creation component to create ProductTranslation entities. In the Creation component, you can attach the Product Translation Detail page and bind the default values in the relation to current entity as shown below.

This will enable you to add versions of different languages on Content Hub within the same entity as below.

Hope this helps!!!

As you may know, a product in Content Hub is an entity. Creating multiple language versions of a product entity does not create multiple entities so if a taxonomy (Country) value (USA) is associated with a product entity language version (English) it cannot be assigned a different value for Germany language version since it is technically one entity behind the scenes for all the language versions.
Alternate is to create multiple product entities one for each language version which may not be a viable option if there are millions of products and/or several different languages to support.
Another option is to create a middle layer (like Azure Functions) to associate the correct taxonomy value based on the language version to the response to the downstream system where the products are consumed.
